# Special characters in XML response received from server

Tags: java, scala

In my Scala code, I am fetching a response from a server using the `getInputStream` method of `HttpUrlConnection` class. The response is XML data. However the data contains HTML entities like `&amp;` and `&apos;`.

Is there a way I can replace these characters with their text equivalent so that I can parse the XML properly?

Comment: Actually `amp` and `apos` are predefined entities in XML, so you shouldn't have problems in parsing an XML file that contains them.

Comment: "parse the XML properly" implies that you're using an XML parser. The ones that come with the JDK will handle these sequences properly, so which one are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's necessary to encode those entities in xml so they don't interfere with its syntax. The `&lt;`(<) and `&gt;` (>) entities make this more obvious. It would be impossible to parse XML whose content was littered with < and > symbols.

Scala's scala.xml package should give you the tools you need to parse your xml.  [Here's some guidance](http://sites.google.com/site/burakemir/scalaxbook.docbk.html?attredirects=0) from the library's author.